# C# dynamic Parsing search result from C# Facebook sdk issue

Tags: c#, facebook-c#-sdk

Trying to execute search on Facebook for pages

```
    if (sq.ObjectType.Equals("page"))
    {
        searchPath = "/search";

        req.q = sq.Query;
        req.type = sq.ObjectType;

    }

    dynamic results = FBClient_.Get(req);
```

And I can't figure out how to parse results.
I cant just simple loop through them.

and I can't see the structure either since it's dynamic object
Somewhere down the line it has this structure:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "name": "Platform-3",
         "category": "Health/medical/pharmacy",
         "id": "362034114769"
      },
      {
         "name": "Platform Expos",
         "category": "Product/service",
         "id": "521000451259682"
      },
      {
         "name": "eXo Platform",
         "category": "Software",
         "id": "152603664817327"
      },
      {
         "name": "Platform 28",
         "category": "Bar",
         "id": "104411956289378"
      },
}
```

but how to get it I'm not sure. How do I convert it into readable format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some mappings.

```
objects => IDictionary<string, object> or IDictionary<string, dynamic>
arrays => IList<object> or IList<dynamic>
number => long if whole number, double if have decimal values
string => string
boolean => bool
```

So in your case you could do this.

```
dynamic result = fb.Get("...")
foreach(var data in result.data) {
    var name = data.name;
    var category = data.category;
    var id = data.id
}
```

Since `result.data` is dynamic which is actually `IList<object>` you can use foreach on it. You could also try this too.

```
dynamic result = fb.Get("...")
IList<dynamic> data = result.data;
foreach(var d in data) {
    string name = d.name;
    string category = d.category;
    string id = d.id
}
```

Or you strongly typed.

```
public class SearchResults {
    public IList<SearchResult> data { get; set;}
}

public class SearchResult {
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string category { get; set; }
}

var result = fb.Get<SearchResults>(...)
```

If you want to follow C# naming standards use `DataContract` and `DataMember`.

```
[DataContract]
public class SearchResults {
    [DataMember(Name = "data")]
    public IList<SearchResult> Data { get; set;}
}

[DataContract]
public class SearchResult {
    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "Category")]
    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would either have to create strongly typed classes to represent your JSON data as prabir has posted, or you could use a JSON library such as [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) which will allow you to interact with your data much more easily. Here is an example from their page:

```
string json = @"{
  ""Name"": ""Apple"",
  ""Expiry"": new Date(1230422400000),
  ""Price"": 3.99,
  ""Sizes"": [
    ""Small"",
    ""Medium"",
    ""Large""
  ]
}";

JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);

string name = (string)o["Name"];
// Apple

JArray sizes = (JArray)o["Sizes"];

string smallest = (string)sizes[0];
```